# Can I store data permanently using flash -on windows?

Tags: windows, adobe-flash

Can I store data permanently using flash -on windows ?

Answer (score 1):

Flash can store data on the users computer using [Local Storage](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/articles/lso/) it defaults to 100k but you can ask the user for permission to store more. It is however more persistent than permanent as the [user can remove it](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/help02.html) whenever he/she chooses to do so.

For details on **how** to implement this with flash I suggest asking that over on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com)